# Better way to make tabs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I haven't added content to correspond with the tabs quite yet. I've only gotten as far as just selecting the tabs.

I'm sure there's a better to do it than the way I've done it.

I'm a big ol' newbie so don't hold back. Any advice is appreciated.

```
import "./Buttons.css";
const Buttons = (props) => {

  const [firstButton, setFirstButton] = useState(false);
  const [secondButton, setSecondButton] = useState(false);
  const [thirdButton, setThirdButton] = useState(false);


  const handleClick = (event) => {
    const currentButton = event.target.id;
    const tabContainer = event.target.parentElement;
    const allButtons = tabContainer.childNodes;

    switch (currentButton) {
      case "1":
        setFirstButton(true);
        setSecondButton(false);
        setThirdButton(false);
        break;
      case "2":
        setFirstButton(false);
        setSecondButton(true);
        setThirdButton(false);
        break;
      case "3":
        setFirstButton(false);
        setSecondButton(false);
        setThirdButton(true);
        break;
    }
  };


  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="tabs">

        <button
          id="1"
          onClick={handleClick}
          className={
            firstButton ? "tab-buttons tab-buttons--active" : "tab-buttons"
          }
        >
          What's New
        </button>

        <button
          id="2"
          onClick={handleClick}
          className={
            secondButton ? "tab-buttons tab-buttons--active" : "tab-buttons"
          }
        >
          Fresh Off The Block
        </button>

        <button
          id="3"
          onClick={handleClick}
          className={
            thirdButton ? "tab-buttons tab-buttons--active" : "tab-buttons"
          }
        >
          Messages From Satan
        </button>

      </div>

      <div id="1" className="tab-content">
        <h1>Example 1</h1>
        <p>more example examples 1</p>
      </div>
      <div id="2" className="tab-content">
        <h1>Example 2</h1>
        <p>more example examples 2</p>
      </div>
      <div id="3" className="tab-content">
        <h1>Example 2</h1>
        <p>more example examples 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Buttons;
```

Comment: I would advise searching for a React tabs tutorial and learning from it, as this is an open ended question not appropriate for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see a couple ways to make your code more readable:

1. Make a component for the tab button -- there is a lot of reused logic

   ```
   function TabButton({label, index, handleClick, isActive}) {
       const activeClassName = "tab-buttons--active";
       const className = `tab-buttons ${isActive ? activeClassName : ""}`;

       return (
           <button
           id={index}
           onClick={handleClick}
           className={className}
           >
           {label}
           </button>
       )
   }
   ```
2. You don't need to do the extra step of validating the ID of the buttons to know which one to set as active. Just use the `isActive` prop.

   ```
   function TabButton({children, handleClick, isActive}) {
       const activeClassName = "tab-buttons--active";
       const className = `tab-buttons ${isActive ? activeClassName : ""}`;

       return (
           <button
           onClick={handleClick}
           className={className}
           >
           {children}
           </button>
       )
   }
   ```
3. You can simplify your state logic since there is only ever going to be one tab that is active at a time. Note: you also have it where none are initially active -- I assume that is a mistake. If not, set `DEFAULT_ACTIVE_TAB` to `-1` since there will be no tabs with that index.

   ```
   const DEFAULT_ACTIVE_TAB = 0

   const Buttons = (props) => {

   const [activeTabIndex, setActiveTabIndex] = React.useState(DEFAULT_ACTIVE_TAB);


       const onClick = (index) => {
           setActiveTabIndex(index)
       }

       return (
           <div className="container">
               <div className="tabs">
                   <TabButton 
                       handleClick={() => onClick(0)} 
                       isActive={activeTabIndex === 0}
                   >
                       What's New
                   </TabButton>

                   <TabButton 
                       handleClick={() => onClick(1)} 
                       isActive={activeTabIndex === 1}
                   >
                       Fresh Off The Block
                   </TabButton>

                   <TabButton 
                       handleClick={() => onClick(2)} 
                       isActive={activeTabIndex === 2}
                   >
                       Messages From Satan
                   </TabButton>
               </div>

           ...

           </div>
       );
   }

   export default Buttons;
   ```
4. You can help make this even better by using a loop to to make your code D.R.Y.

   ```
   const DEFAULT_ACTIVE_TAB = 0
   const TAB_NAMES = ["What's New", "Fresh Off The Block", "Messages From Satan"]

   const Buttons = (props) => {

   const [activeTabIndex, setActiveTabIndex] = React.useState(DEFAULT_ACTIVE_TAB);


       const onClick = (index) => {
           setActiveTabIndex(index)
       }

       return (
           <div className="container">
               <div className="tabs">
                   {TAB_NAMES.map((tabName, index) => (
                       <TabButton 
                           handleClick={() => onClick(index)} 
                           isActive={activeTabIndex === index}
                       >
                           {tabName}
                       </TabButton>
                   )}
               </div>

           ...

           </div>
       );
   }

   export default Buttons;
   ```

Comment: I'll be using your advice. Thanks for taking the time for doing this, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to achieve what you're trying to do, but I tend to take this approach:

```
// Will return an object containing all the required tab components.
// Such as: { TabA, TabB, etc... }
import tabs from "./Tabs";

const TabContext = React.createContext({});

// This will iterate all of the relevant buttons that need to be created
// in order to represent each tab. 
// Each button will be compared to the same set of logic that checks if 
// the button has been clicked and applies any required styling.
const Buttons = () => (
    <div>
        <TabContext.Consumer>{({ activeTab, setActiveTab }) => (
            tabs.map((_, index) => (
                <button 
                    className={classNames("tab", { active: activeTab === index })}
                    onClick={() => setActiveTab(index)}
                    key={`tab-${index}`}>
                        Tab { index }
                </button>
            ))
        )}</TabContext.Consumer>
    </div>
);

const Parent = () => {
    // The index of the tab you are attempting to select.
    const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(0);

    // Retrieve the active tab Component with the selected index.
    // This updates whenever the state changes, so you can trust that the returned object will be correct.
    const Tab = useMemo(() => tabs[activeTab], [tabs, activeTab]);

    return (
        <TabContext.Provider value={{
            activeTab,
            setActiveTab
        }}>
            <Buttons />
            <Tab />
        </TabContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Inside of the `./Tabs.js` file you would have something along the lines of:

```
export const TabA = () => <div>Tab A</div>;
export const TabB = () => <div>Tab B</div>;
export const TabC = () => <div>Tab C</div>;
```

Obviously, this is a very basic approach, and there are tons of ways you can customise this. But for the most part, I feel this will set you on the right track without being too confusing.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this type:

```
    //your components
    import { useState } from "react";
    import GraphicalAnalytics from "../components/account/admin/GraphicalAnalytics";
    import MyADsPostTable from "../components/account/admin/MyADsPostTable";
    import ShopInformation from "../components/account/admin/ShopInformation";
    import UserInformation from "../components/account/admin/UserInformation";
    import CreateShop from "../components/account/create-shop/CreateShop";
    import AddUser from "../components/account/super-admin/AddUser";
    import UsersTable from "../components/account/super-admin/UsersTable";
    import UserProfile from "../components/account/user-profile/UserProfile";
    
    // tabs list
    const list = [
      "Graphical Analytics",
      "Manage Users",
      "User Profile",
      "Create Shop",
      "Settings",
      "My ADs Posts",
      "Shop Information",
      "Add User"
    ];
    // main Dashboard Component Function
    const Dashboard = () => {
      // tab switching handler state - tabIndex
      const [tabIndex, setTabIndex] = useState(1);
      const [showSideNav, setShowSideNav] = useState(false);
    
      return (
        <div className="container-x container-y">
          {showSideNav ? (
            <div className="fixed left-0 top-0 w-full h-full bg-[#00000020] z-50">
              <SideNavigator
                tabIndex={tabIndex}
                setTabIndex={setTabIndex}
                setShowSideNav={setShowSideNav}
              />
            </div>
          ) : null}
          <div className="flex items-center justify-start gap-2 lg:hidden m-2" onClick={() => setShowSideNav(true)}><i className="icon-menu" /><p className="font-bold text-xl">Dashboard</p></div>
          <div className="grid grid-cols-12 gap-5 rounded-lg bg-gray-100 p-3 lg:p-5">
            <div className="hidden lg:block col-span-12 lg:col-span-3 min-h-[70vh] rounded-lg bg-white border">
              <h3 className="text-lg lg:text-xl 2xl:text-2xl font-bold px-3 py-2 bg-[#024c8e] text-white mb-3 rounded-t-lg">
                Dashboard 
              </h3>
              <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-2">
                {list.map((item, i) => {
                  return (
                    <div
                      key={i}
                      className={`px-3 py-1 rounded-lg bg-white hover:bg-[#024c8c] hover:text-white cursor-pointer ${
                        tabIndex === i + 1 ? "bg-[#024c8c] text-white" : ""
                      }`}
                      onClick={() => setTabIndex(i + 1)}
                    >
                      {item}
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-span-12 lg:col-span-9">
              {tabIndex === 1 ? <GraphicalAnalytics /> : null}
              {tabIndex === 2 ? <UsersTable /> : null}
              {tabIndex === 3 ? <UserProfile /> : null}
              {tabIndex === 4 ? <CreateShop /> : null}
              {tabIndex === 5 ? <UserInformation /> : null}
              {tabIndex === 6 ? <MyADsPostTable /> : null}
              {tabIndex === 7 ? <ShopInformation /> : null}
              {tabIndex === 8 ? <AddUser /> : null}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Dashboard;
    
    const SideNavigator = ({ tabIndex, setTabIndex, setShowSideNav }) => {
      return (
        <div className="pt-20 block lg:hidden w-[90%] h-full rounded-lg bg-white border">
          <h3 className="text-lg lg:text-xl 2xl:text-2xl font-bold px-3 py-2 bg-[#024c8e] text-white mb-3 rounded-t-lg flex items-center justify-between gap-2">
            Dashboard <i className="icon-close" onClick={() => setShowSideNav(false)}/>
          </h3>
          <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-2">
            {list.map((item, i) => {
              return (
                <div
                  key={i}
                  className={`px-3 py-1 rounded-lg bg-white hover:bg-[#024c8c] hover:text-white cursor-pointer ${
                    tabIndex === i + 1 ? "bg-[#024c8c] text-white" : ""
                  }`}
                  onClick={() => {
                    setTabIndex(i + 1);
                    setShowSideNav(false)
                  }}
                >
                  {item}
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };
```

You can visit this site to see the output of this code live: https://sell-bazar-client.vercel.app/dashboard